# java apache tomcat is not detecting the jsp file even when it exists

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat

I have come across to a strange problem where apache tomcat server is showing 404 server code. But some of the files are being detected by the system. I am using eclipse for the development.

Any suggestions?!

## EDIT 1 :

i have checked the webapps folder of CATALINA_HOME but nothing is there related to the project.

Comment: Can you give an idea of what your directory structure under tomcat/webapps looks like?  If it's returning a 404 it is likely that your web application structure is either not there, or incorrect.

Comment: I am using eclipse helios for my development, and I created a dynamic web project in that. So, its the default structure provided by the eclispe ide.

Comment: How are you deploying to tomcat?  Find the tomcat-root/webapps directory and if your files are not there, that is your issue.

Comment: @Brad well, I have configured tomcat in my eclipse and because of that eclispe dynamically deploys webapp to the directory.

Comment: Fair enough, but have you checked the directory to verify that it actually happened? This is still the best explanation for a 404 not found error.

Comment: no nothing is the in webapps folder of tomcat.

Comment: Now heres a new problem, I have removed and added the project in the server tab of the eclipse, and now..the project is not at all running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommending seeing if you can deploy a WAR file successfully in Tomcat without using Eclipse.

Right now it sounds like you don't understand Java web apps or Tomcat very well.

When you throw Eclipse on top of it there's too much ignorance to make progress.

So remove one of the things you don't understand.  See if you can make the WAR file, deploy it manually, and see your JSP in the browser by hand.  Once that works, you have a baseline for comparing how Eclipse needs to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible issue that might cause similar problems is if you have deployed your application in the root context (i.e. under the name ROOT) and the jsp in question is in a folder like /manager, while you also have the manager application. In this case, Tomcat will give preference to the manager application, rather than the /manager path inside the ROOT application

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse wont always deploy dynamically aka hot deploy and you need to make it re-deploy. So sure shot way of checking is to actually going into the war file, or the root directory and checking if the jsp exists. 
Also you have to provided much information as to what kind of a web application it is, for me to understand the problem better. For example, in struts a wrong entry in struts-config.xml will result in 404 even if the intended jsp is present.

Comment: its a dynamic web project of eclipse. And I used to simply click right on the project name and then run -> run on server.

Comment: do you mean the folder of CATALINA_HOME?!! Yes I checked it..and nothign is there in webapps.